# Practical use of oop in R

Tags: machine-learning, r, data-mining, programming

R supports a wide range of OOP designs like s3,s4,RC and others via packages,and it's a bit overwhelming to decide on which to use and a more basic question that I have is when and where do you use OOP  while doing  machine learning or data analytics ,can someone answer this from a data scientist/ML practitioner point of view .

I'm aware of how OOP works in R at a superficial level ,but

> should I invest time in learning OOP in R ?
>   how practical is it from a data science point of view  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used `S3`, `S4` and `R6` (you forgot that one in your overview ;)). I would agree with Hadley Wickham that `S3` is [sufficient for most tasks](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html#picking-a-system). However, this is only required if you start building advanced functions that operate on objects. Say for example you build a model with one function and you want to create a `summary` and `print` function for the object returned by your model building function. For general Data Science purposes I would say that it helps to know the systems but none of them are very good examples of real OOP. For that I would recommend to work in Python, Ruby or Java. All have been build with OOP in mind.

In regards to knowing OOP, I think it is vital for someone involved in ML. Not when you are prototyping in R or Python but definitely when you start working on production code. I think [this Quora thread](https://www.quora.com/Do-researchers-in-computer-vision-and-machine-learning-write-object-oriented-code-when-experimenting-with-ideas) gives a good run down on when OOP becomes important in ML.

If your focus is more on statistics in R it may be of less importance.

Comment: I feel like S3 is the weirdest implementation of OOP.especially coming from java ,it feels very different, to say the least,and for the most part, I've never come across some code that uses OOP while working on some dataset.

Comment: Totally agree, I am not even sure how S3 came to be called OOP, however within R it is used a lot since that is how functions such as `summary` and `print` know which function to dispatch.

Comment: For some context, `R` is an open source clone of another language called `S`, hence, `S3` and `S4` types. If you want to understand their design I'd look into that language instead.